# Make IIS website public (to the network) from within Parallels

Tags: visual-studio-2010, networking, iis-7, virtual-machine, parallels

I've got [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/ca/products/desktop/) running on my Macbook Pro and I'm developing a small application that needs to be run exclusively on mobile devices (using [sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)).

The problem is that my Windows 7 IP address in Parallels is **10.211.55.0/24** and our local network is **192.168.1.0/24**

Accessing the IIS application via Firefox or IE is not acceptable since I need to test on the iPad and iPhone.

Does anyone know how to expose IIS applications to the network from within a Parallels VM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget I ever asked such a stupid question.

I simply had to put my VM in **Bridge** mode rather than **Shared Network**

I was looking in the wrong place (Parallels config rather than VM config)

Comment: A detailed process on how to configure Win7 correctly is here:  http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer